# How to tell if a button was clicked

Tags: html

I need to determine which button was selected.  I tried the code below but is does not execute when the cmdSubmit button is selected.  My thought is to only validate the data on the form for the cmdSubmit button and return false if there are errors found.  If another button is select, return true.

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="ProjectCensus.php" onsubmit="return validateForm(myForm)">
<input class="button" type="submit" name='cmdSubmit' id="cmdSubmit" value="Submit" />

function validateForm(thisform) 
{
    with (thisform) 
    var blnReturn = true;
    alert("In validateForm");
 if (document.getElementById('cmdSubmit').onclick == true)
 {
     validate data on form.  If there are errors, return false 
 } else
 {
     return true;
 }
```

Comment: Try putting an onclick handler on the button, doing the validation, and then submitting the form in javascript if it passes.  Also, always use === (not ==).

Comment: How do I submit the form in javascript?  I am very new to HTML, JavaScript and PHP but I am trying.

Comment: You can google this stuff quite easily but may I suggest that you're having a hard time assimilating the information because you need more basic knowledge?  Please, consider following a book or comprehensive tutorial.  There's much to learn and no royal road to competence.